# How to represent a counts of data from a query with manual representation each row?

Tags: mysql

I am not a DBA but still trying to figure it out how to make the below problem work.
I am retrieving ONLY counts from DB for respective class of animals. 
Now after retrieving counts from that query with multiple joins i get all the counts (mentioned in the total count column)
but i want to represent that data with two more column that represent type and description. but i am not able to get how to do it.
Like, i am getting total counts from a query which have joins i want to display those counts as

```
Type_of_animal|description                            |total_count
------------- |---------------------------------------|-----------
Reptiles      |Reptiles are cold-blooded vertebrates  | 5000
Mammals       |People are mammals                     | 80000
Birds         |Any which have feathers                | 1000000
```

i want to represent those counts with a manually naming a type_of_animal and its description as out against every count.

one query is

```
SELECT count(catmang.category_id) AS 'Total Counts'
FROM category catmang
JOIN category_identifier catident ON catident.category_id = catmang.category_id
WHERE category_id = 5
```

Comment: Please show us the query you are currently using. Edit this into your question, dont put this in a comment

Comment: hmmm... what is the category in `FROM category catmang` mean?

Comment: Category is a table which have all relational table ids .. suppose i want to get all reptiles then for that i have a category id mapped to category table. and category_identifier is a table which have the category id as 5 and the data as snakes , lizards and so on and these are reptiles and it can only be identified by its id 5 but there is no table which have its code like reptiles or Mammals or birds and we cant add any table i have to work with what i have. so i have to mention as for total counts on category 5 will be reptiles and that i need to mention in the rows :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean:

```
SELECT category_identifier.*, COUNT(*) as total_count
FROM category_identifier
LEFT JOIN category using(category_id)
GROUP BY category_identifier.category_id
```

(possibly with category_identifier.* exchanged for .type and .description)

**update**

since original poster doesn't want to use data that is actually in the database (stripping all the benefits from having it in the database), a "virtual" table can be created, but it's quite verbose and annoying. add this join:

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 'Reptiles' as Type_of_animal, 
         'Reptiles are cold-blooded vertebrates' as description, 
         1 as category_id
  UNION
  SELECT 'Mammals' as Type_of_animal, 
         'Reptiles are cold-blooded vertebrates' as description,
         2 as category_id
  UNION
  .......
) as texts USING(category_id)
```

and in the select use texts.type_of_animal, texts.description. you have to modify the category_ids probably ...

Comment: No. there no row that says its reptile or have any description.

Comment: @ami so ... how do you know? do you have a sheet of paper where the ids and associated descriptions and type_of_animals are written down? if so ... put them into the database and join them together. everything else is unnecessarily complex (one could say ... foolish)

Comment: Yes i agree with you , its more of a foolish requirement :) but before i put my views i just want to be sure that is there any way in DB where while getting   counts of any item,  i can mention row as some string and count against it which i mentioned in the above table. where Type_of_animal|description is hardcoded or some way to write against counts.

Comment: if you absolutely don't want to actually put it into the database, join with a virtual table ... adapting post ... will take a moment

Comment: Oh , yes that could be. but not sure how to do that, do you have any links where i can read stuff regarding  virtual table. sorry for such ask but i am not a DB so trying best to get things happen some way.

Comment: Thanks Jakumi, YOU ROCK :)

Comment: @ami if this answers your question, feel free to mark it as the solution ;o)